# Excel VBA Function to Return True or False based on Cell Background Colors in a Range

Tags: excel, function, sorting, colors, range

I keep a spreadsheet of my timeline at work and when I meet and expect to meet certain milestones. The data (dates) is stored left-to-right and each project has it's own row. The milestones are permantely set and occupy Range(O:AA). My data is color coded as Green (Complete), Orange(Deadline), Blue(Not working on), Red(Not applicable).

What I would like to do is write a function that would check if a cell contained an orange color background(Color index 6) and return a TRUE or FALSE based on that. Basically I want to aggregate all of the deadlines across all of the columns. Eventually I would like to integrate a date check as well so I can see which deadlines are approaching.

```
Function ScanForColor(Dates As Range) as Boolean
    If ScanForColor.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        ScanForColor = True
    Else
        ScanForColor = False
End Function
```

I would like to call the function in a cell like =ScanForColor(O3:AA3) and I will have the ScanForColor function in column AB to hold the values for filtering the document.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to enter one of four codes into each cell instead? This way you can use regular workbook formulae to do the aggregation. You can still vary the background colour using conditional formatting -- conditional formats for three states, and the default cell colour for the fourth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this will do the trick!

```
Function ScanForColor(Cells As Range, ColorValue As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Cells
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorValue Then
            ScanForColor = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

This will allow you to call and test different color values....

Comment: Thank you very much GraGra. This helped me build the report I am working.